# How do I format numbers to display comas?

Tags: swift

I am just getting started with programming, and this is the very first IOS app that I have built on my own. You are probably very familiar with this, can you tell me how to format numbers to display a coma for very large numbers? I want my numbers to have commas like in 1,000 instead of 1000. I was able to eliminate the decimal places using "$.0f" but I am not sure if there is an easy way of adding the commas. I know all of you are awesome, experienced programmers, but please share the easiest implementation of this as I am just a beginner. I am using Swift and SwiftUI on Xcode. See the image below to see my code and what the app looks like.

Thanks a lot!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBhKx.png

Comment: @JoakimDanielson OP is using SwiftUI. No need to use `NumberFormatter`.  All OP needs is to format his integer with number: `Text(1_000_000, format: .number)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @LeoDabus's comment. I updated the answer according to his contribution.**

SwiftUI's Text struct has initializer with format setting.

```
Text(_ input: Equatable, format: FormatStyle)
```

This initializer can be usable in your case.

```
Text(1000, format: .number)
```

This will formats the number with device's local separator settings.

***Previous answer below was for UIKit***

You can use NumberFormatter class to get formatted numbers as String.

I'm sharing a sample function to understand how the conversion works.

```
func getFormattedNumber(_ number: Int) -> String? {
    let nsNumber = NSNumber(value: number) // NumberFormatter class uses NSNumber type for conversion.
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal // numberStyle determines how formatter converts the number.

    return numberFormatter.string(from: nsNumber)
}
```

Comment: **"NumberFormatter class uses NSNumber type for conversion."** Not necessarily. You can use `Formatter`'s method `string(for: Any)` and pass any `Numeric` type. In your case `numberFormatter.string(for: number)`. Note also that `NumberFormatter` `groupingSeparator` will be determined by the device's locale settings. Btw OP is using SwiftUI not UIKit.

Comment: Thank you a lot! How do I go about handling options in the number formatter? Should I just use a "!" next to the values that I want to unwrap? Or should I add a coalescent operator somewhere inside the function with a default error message? Thanks!

Comment: You can use guard statement inside the function and you can return non optional value.